# add to cart button without going to the check out page

Tags: checkout, cart

I want plugin or button that makes things like this.

Example : When user clicks on "add to cart" the items should go the cart without loading the current page. like crazydeals.

Comment: If you want to add to cart in ajax way you may use datta ajax mini cart which is a free extension.

Answer (score 0):

Please update from

```
System -> Configuration -> Checkout -> Shopping Cart -> Set After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart = Yes
```

Check below screenshot.

[image]